# How to increate the timeout for tooltips in SSRS?

Tags: internet-explorer, tooltip, reporting-services

I was wondering how to increate the time before a tooltip disappears when viewing a report in IE.

edit: Sorry I did some more research on it and I know I can't change the IE timeout, so any suggestions on how to use javascript to create tooltips?

Comment: a possible solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0bb5af6-ca4f-4b67-a0f0-2e2ea297e98c/increase-tooltip-display-time

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from within the browser.  The timeout is controlled by a system setting that should only be set by the user.  However, you can implement your own tooltip-like control in DHTML+Javascript and have whatever timeout you want.